# How to generate just a single row for each product in a Dataflow Profiles export?

Tags: magento-1.9, export, dataflow

We are exporting a list of products from Magento 1.9 using a Dataflow Profiles export.

The resulting export file includes multiple rows for each product if the product has more than one image (eg if the product has 3 images there will be 3 rows for the product in the resulting CSV file).

We would like to have just a single row per product regardless of the number of images for each product.

I assume this can be done by adding some XML to the "Actions XML" field.

How can we force the export to only generate a single line for each product (always just the first line if there is more than one line per product)?